Running the code take too long
I am trying to run this code but it takes a very long time and does not finish.
\[Lambda]1U238 = 4.9150210*10^-18; \[Lambda]2Th234 = 
 3.3281466*10^-7; \[Lambda]3Pa234 = 2.8731343*10^-5; \[Lambda]4U234 = 
 8.945138*10^-14; \[Lambda]5Th230 = 2.91250847*10^-13;
\[Lambda]6Ra226 = 1.3725196*10^-11; \[Lambda]7Rn220 = 
 2.0977751*10^-6; \[Lambda]8Po218 = 3.729817*10^-3; \[Lambda]9At218 = 
 5.4140625*10^-1; \[Lambda]10Bi214 = 5.8599695*10^-4;
\[Lambda]11Po214 = 4.2395693*10^3; \[Lambda]12Pb210 = 
 9.8920332*10^-10; \[Lambda]13Bi210 = 
 1.6003251*10^-6; \[Lambda]14Po210 = 
 5.7964051*10^-8; \[Lambda]15Bb206 = 0;
\[Lambda]Np238 = 
  3.8212556*10^-6 \[Lambda]Pb214 = 
   4.2672413*10^-4 \[Lambda]Tl210 = 8.8846153*10^-3;

N1U238 = Sum[(-1)^(n)*\[Lambda]1U238^n*t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N2Th234 = \[Lambda]1U238*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*\[Lambda]2Th234^(n - 1 - i),
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N3Pa234 = \[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*\[Lambda]3Pa234^(n - 1 - j),
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N4U234 = \[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*\[Lambda]4U234^(n - 1 - k), {k, 
           0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];


N5Th230 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*\[Lambda]5Th230^(n - 1 - l), {l,
              0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N6Ra226 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*\[Lambda]6Ra226^(n - 1 - 
                  p), {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N7Rn220 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*\[Lambda]7Rn220^(n - 1 - 
                    q), {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];
Plot[{N7Rn220}, {t, 0, 15000000000}]


N8Po218 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*
                 
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)*\[Lambda]8Po218^(n - 1 - 
                    r), {r, 0, q}]
                , {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N9At218 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)*
                   
                   Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(s - r)*\[Lambda]9At218^(n - 
                    1 - s), {s, 0, r}],
                  {r, 0, q}],
                {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];
N10Bi214 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*\
\[Lambda]9At218*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)*
                   Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(s - r)*
                    
                    Sum[\[Lambda]9At218^(z - s)*\[Lambda]10Bi214^(n - 
                    1 - z), {z, 0, s}],
                    {s, 0, r}],
                  {r, 0, q}],
                {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N11Po214 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*\
\[Lambda]9At218*\[Lambda]10Bi214*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i
       *Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)
         *Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)
           *Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)
             *Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)
               *Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)
                 *Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)
                   *Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(s - r)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]9At218^(z - s)*
                    
                    Sum[\[Lambda]10Bi214^(u - 
                    z)*\[Lambda]11Po214^(n - 1 - u), {u, 0, z}]
                    , {z, 0, s}],
                    {s, 0, r}],
                  {r, 0, q}],
                {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]
     *t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N12Pb210 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*\
\[Lambda]9At218*\[Lambda]10Bi214*\[Lambda]11Po214*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)*
                   Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(s - r)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]9At218^(z - s)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]10Bi214^(u - z)*
                    
                    Sum[\[Lambda]11Po214^(v - 
                    u)*\[Lambda]12Pb210^(n - 1 - v),
                    {v, 0, u}],
                    {u, 0, z}],
                    {z, 0, s}],
                    {s, 0, r}],
                  {r, 0, q}],
                {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]*t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];


N13Bi210 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*\
\[Lambda]9At218*\[Lambda]10Bi214*\[Lambda]11Po214*\[Lambda]12Pb210*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(p - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(q - p)*
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(r - q)*
                   Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(s - r)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]9At218^(z - s)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]10Bi214^(u - z)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]11Po214^(v - u)*
                    
                    Sum[\[Lambda]12Pb210^(w - 
                    v)*\[Lambda]13Bi210^(n - 1 - w),
                    {w, 0, v}],
                    {v, 0, u}],
                    {u, 0, z}],
                    {z, 0, s}],
                    {s, 0, r}],
                  {r, 0, q}],
                {q, 0, p}],
              {p, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]*t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];

N14Po210 = \
\[Lambda]1U238*\[Lambda]2Th234*\[Lambda]3Pa234*\[Lambda]4U234*\
\[Lambda]5Th230*\[Lambda]6Ra226*\[Lambda]7Rn220*\[Lambda]8Po218*\
\[Lambda]9At218*\[Lambda]10Bi214*\[Lambda]11Po214*\[Lambda]12Pb210*\
\[Lambda]13Bi210*
   Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
     Sum[\[Lambda]1U238^i*
       Sum[\[Lambda]2Th234^(j - i)*
         Sum[\[Lambda]3Pa234^(k - j)*
           Sum[\[Lambda]4U234^(l - k)*
             Sum[\[Lambda]5Th230^(m - l)*
               Sum[\[Lambda]6Ra226^(p - k)*
                 Sum[\[Lambda]7Rn220^(q - p)*
                   Sum[\[Lambda]8Po218^(r - q)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]9At218^(s - r)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]10Bi214^(z - s)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]11Po214^(u - z)*
                    Sum[\[Lambda]12Pb210^(v - u)*
                    
                    Sum[\[Lambda]13Bi210^(w - 
                    v)*\[Lambda]14Po210^(n - 1 - w),
                    {w, 0, v}],
                    {v, 0, u}],
                    {u, 0, z}],
                    {z, 0, s}],
                    {s, 0, r}],
                    {r, 0, q}],
                  {q, 0, p}],
                {p, 0, m}],
              {m, 0, l}],
            {l, 0, k}],
          {k, 0, j}],
        {j, 0, i}],
      {i, 0, n - 1}]*t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}];


N15Bb206 = 
  1 - N1U238 - N2Th234 - N3Pa234 - N4U234 - N5Th230 - N6Ra226 - 
   N7Rn220 - N8Po218 - N9At218 - N10Bi214 - N11Po214 - N12Pb210 - 
   N13Bi210 - N14Po210;

Plot[{N1U238}, {t, 0, 1000000000000000000}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time (s)", Black, 10], 
   Style["U238", Black, 10]}] 

What is the problem with this code and how can this problem be solved?
Is it possible to know how long the code will take to complete, for example, as happens with download programs?
What is the problem with this code and how can this problem be solved? Is it possible to know how long the code will take to complete, for example, as happens with download programs?
What is the problem with this code and how can this problem be solved? Is it possible to know how long the code will take to complete, for example, as happens with download programs?

You've posted a very large chunk of code. Please run each line separately and determine, where it gets stuck. Note that you have very complicated sums with multiple indices, so it is no surprise Mathematica takes long time (or it likely even can't calculate them).

many calulations e.g. N10Bi214, N9At218 etc generate precision errors and end up being 0. So not sure if that's what you want anyway

What does this have to do with "differential-equations" or "difference-equations"? Could you give a more descriptive title?
